# How to capture by value in lambda functions?

Tags: python-3.x

Every now and then, I encounter a behavior in Python that I find surprising and don't quite know how to search a solution for. Apologies for the non-pythonic title, I am personally more versed in C++.

Here is a minimal example of the issue I am having:

```py
# create a dict with char => int
>> x = { key: val for val, key in enumerate('abcdef') }

# create lambda functions to print each key in order
>> y = [ lambda: print(key) for key in x.keys() ]

# I think I understand the result, but find it surprising and don't know how to fix it
>> y[0]()
f
```

In this example, I would expect `y[0]()` to print `a` instead. My best guess for why this is not the case is that somehow the lambda functions capture the variable `key` "by reference", and that reference then persists outside of the list comprehension because it has been captured. Did I get that right? Please help me understand.

How can I change this code to make the lambda function at index `k` print the letter `'a'+k` instead?

Comment: My bad, seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2295290/472610

Comment: FWIW, the top answers on that post are outdated. Please use `functools.partial` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10101476/9816919).

Comment: Incidentally, the explanation for this behavior is *not* that the expression `key` is passed by reference, because expressions can only be passed by value in Python. The reason for this oddity is late binding, that is, a variable is bound to a particular value when it is used, and not when a lambda is created; and since all the lambdas are created in the same scope, where they are executed `key` is resolved to the same value, which is, the last value it had in the iteration.